# Extend Upsell Products

Tags: up-sells, product-edit

Hello I am trying to find out how to "duplicate" the upsell products functionality.

Meaning:

- An additional tab on the product edit screen - i.e. Upsell2 so the collection can be saved
- Cloned Upsell block for product page that behaves same way , but uses different collection..

On first guess, it seems you could build the collection and then reuse the same block but set a diff template/collection.

But the part about building the grid + extra collection is the tricky part for me . If anyone has answers or advice it is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I won't copy it given the length, but see this guide. http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/

Comment: You could add an extra info in the upsell collection like "column", and then put all your upsell products and assign them 1 or 2 depending on which column you want them in. You'd then simply need to modify upsell.phtml to display both columns.